# Truncating strings

Tags: java, sql, ibatis, mysql-connector

I'm working with third party user data that may or may not fit into our database. The data needs to be truncated if it is too long.

We are using IBatis with Connector/J. If the data is too long a SQL exception is thrown. I have had two choices: either truncate the strings in Java or truncate the strings in sql using substring.

I don't like truncating the strings in sql, because I am writing table structure in our Ibatis XML, but SQL on the other hand knows about our database collation (which isn't consistent and would be expensive to make consistent) and can truncate string in a multibyte safe manner.

Is there a way to have the Connector/J just straight insert this SQL and if not which route would people recommend?

Comment: How're you importing the data?  I'm wondering if you can truncate the text in the INSERT statements in the scripts themselves... or can you truncate the text when exporting it from the 3rd party?

Comment: Do you mean in Ibatis? That's what I am doing and I don't like it because I have to write table structure into insert statements that should be agnostic about it. I don't actually export the data from the 3rd party, they send it in via XML. I could write it into the XSD, but that would prevent them from sending their data in the first place if it is too long.

I want their data, I just need to truncate it if it is too long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html) it's possible that inserting data that exceeds the length could be treated as a warning:

> Inserting a string into a string
>   column (CHAR, VARCHAR, TEXT, or BLOB)
>   that exceeds the column's maximum
>   length. The value is truncated to the
>   column's maximum length.

One of the Connector/J properties is `jdbcCompliantTruncation`. This is [its description](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html):

> This sets whether Connector/J should
>   throw java.sql.DataTruncation
>   exceptions when data is truncated.
>   This is required by the JDBC
>   specification when connected to a
>   server that supports warnings (MySQL
>   4.1.0 and newer). This property has no effect if the server sql-mode includes
>   STRICT_TRANS_TABLES. Note that if
>   STRICT_TRANS_TABLES is not set, it
>   will be set as a result of using this
>   connection string option.

If I understand correctly then setting this property to false doesn't throw the exception but inserts the truncated data. This solution doesn't require you to truncate the data in program code or SQL statements, but delegates it to the database.